# Prestashop. How to add Datepicker to order confirmation

Tags: jquery, datepicker, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to ask, if someone can help me with Prestashop. I need to add Datepicker with date and time in Order Confirmation form. On selecting type of delivery, I have to use this value in order email template which will be sent to customer and administrator after completing order.
If someone can help, it will be nice. I am new in Prestashop so every solution will be welcome to implement this without buying the paid module.
Thanks

Comment: If you're new on prestashop I'll suggest this module: https://addons.prestashop.com/it/iscrizione-processo-di-ordinazione/19008-custom-fields-add-extra-field-to-checkout-order-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add datepicker in Prestashop by including JQuery for datepicker

```
$this->context->controller->addJQueryUi('ui.datepicker');
```

Then, add datepicker on the element where you want to display like:

```
$('#delivery_date').datepicker(); in your JS file.
```